# How to put multiple boxes next to each other in a vertically scrollable view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, view, kotlin

I have a problem. I am still a beginner with Android Development.
I made a ScrollView and now it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of ScrollView with white boxes]

But I want to have 3 x N  boxes in a vertically scrollable view like this:

[image: Drawing of the scrollable view I want]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The answer is RecyclerView

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński oh nice I didnt know there was something like that since it wasnt inside the Palette

Comment: what have you tried so far? post your code.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh i got it figured out its alright

Comment: @Kisokare answer this question then. post your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, I found the answer.
I used a RecyclerView and I pushed my boxes into the RecyclerView like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9VCg.jpg)